# Change address or port of the client destination httpservlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am currently setting up a server using HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest and I am wondering whether I could send the response based on the request to other IP address or same IP address but different port. The idea is I create an authentication module in Java and the user is using Java application to login and the application will trigger the browser so that user will login in the browser. After login is successful, the browser will redirect back to authentication module and instead sending the response back to the browser I will send it to the Java application in different port(192.168.1.13:8993 for example).

My code is basically something like this

```
@Override
    public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject clientSubject, Subject serviceSubject)
            throws AuthException {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) messageInfo.getRequestMessage();
        log.warning("validate request");
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) messageInfo.getResponseMessage();
        String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
        final HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        final String requestUrl = getRequestUrl(request);
        final String returnToUrl = getReturnToURL(request);
        log.info(String.format("Incoming authentication request on \"%s\", expecting return to \"%s\".", requestUrl,
                returnToUrl));
        UserPrincipal principal;
        try {
            if (requestUrl.startsWith(returnToUrl)) {
                    log.info("Verifying authentication.");
                    principal = verifyReturningUser(request);
                    if (principal != null) {
                        storePrincipal(session, principal, clientSubject);
                        session.setAttribute(UserPrincipal.SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY, principal);
                        String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute(ATTR_KEY_USER_REDIRECT_URL);
                        session.removeAttribute(ATTR_KEY_USER_REDIRECT_URL);
                        response.addHeader(HTTP_HEADER_AUTH_KEY, HTTP_HEADER_AUTH_VALUE_SUCCESS);
                        if (redirectUrl != null) {
//Send the response back of redirect to /rest into destination with other IP address or the same address but different port.
                            response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
                            log.info(String.format("Initial authentication successful. Redirecting back to: %s",
                                    redirectUrl));
                        } else {
                            log.info("No redirect URL found.");
                        }

                        return AuthStatus.SEND_SUCCESS;
                    }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: 1. I dont understand few sentences, for example the first. Can You show parts of code? 2. Main idea isn't stupid, sometimes I have seen similar (for example in Apache Wicket FAQ, with SSL support for auth port). 3. I can't believe You are writing in raw Java, without kind of framework. 1+3 let me think, no realisation yet exist.

Comment: @JacekCz I am implementing javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule for it. I will put some of the code above as it is too long there. But is it possible to send the response to other address or other port of the same address of the client destination?

Comment: A form can include a post address different than the original one (but it could look like a Cross Site Request Forgery attack), and the server can redirect to anywhere. Maybe you could have a look to the [CAS protocol] for an example where the authentication is done on a different URL than the application one.

Comment: I understand better. Http part (integration with servlet technology) ... it is raw java/servlet code, or servlet framework? Depends on time in request/response cycle, not everything is possible with response if tries are to early/to late.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could you give me how can I implement the CAS protocol for my code as I don't think it is suitable with my code.

Comment: @JacekCz I also combined with Apache for retrieving user's info as I am implementing OAuth framework for log in with third party authenticator. The response will be sent after the log in is successful from the website and the user info has been retrieved. I highlighted where I want to set the destination to other port or address with the comment line.